# Display data passed into dataLayer in Google Analytics using GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layers

How can I display data passed into `dataLayer` in Google Analytics using GTM?

Let me share with you what I was able to do so far.

**1** There is a part in my client side JavaScript code from where I am sending a data. I am doing it in this way: `dataLayer.push({startedPlaying: true});`.

**2** Now in GTM I am getting the data in a Message format:
[image]

Now I would like to send the data directly to Google Analytics. And in Google Analytics I would like to keep track of how many times such a message was sent from the client (in my example it means how many times a song play button was clicked).

I understand that the question may be a little bit too broad, but if it is so, then answer it is broadly as well, so that I got my next learning directions in the matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of sending `startedPlaying: true`, try sending `event: 'started-playing'`this is how you send a datalayer event.

Then configure a custom event trigger in GTM to trigger off of the "`started-playing`" datalayer event.
[image]

Then create a Google Analytics tag of the "event" type and put in all the event information about this event to be sent to GA and attach the trigger created above. Like so:
[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot. I was able to do everything you explained. But how can I keep a count of how many times the audio was started on my website in Google Analytics? In other words how can I increment a value in Google analytics each time someone starts to listen an audio?

Comment: Actually I see no point in using event instead of a raw variable. Could you explain why it is better to use an event, please?

Comment: Why do you want to increment it? Using an event so that you can use GTM to create a trigger easily. What additional information do you gain for using "started-playing: true"?

Comment: Ok, I see the point now, thank you. One last question, what GA and GTM should I cover in order to implement the following: there is an audio file on my website, I want to see in GA how many users started listening the audio, how many reached 25% of audio, 50% etc. I have no issue accessing the data inside website itself (for one user), now I want to be able to see the data (for all users) in GA and send the data from website to GA through GTM. I am very new to GA, what should I cover to be able to implement the above? Thank you.

Comment: How is the audio file hosted? Do you know how to get the % reached?

Comment: Yes, I possess all the needed data when on client side. It is just a matter of presenting the data in the correct format and sending it to GTM and then restructuring it there and sending up to GA for displaying.

Comment: Could you create a short chat for us? I believe I lack privileges right now.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183065/display-data-passed-into-datalayer-in-google-analytics-using-gtm